# CMake Linking custom libraries with executable results in undef. references

Tags: c++, cmake, linker

I'm new to CMake and have a feeling that I miss something.
Here is the problem:
I build a shared object called "wrapper" as shown below.

```
add_library(wrapper SHARED
        dh-wrap.cpp)

target_link_options(wrapper PUBLIC -Wl,--no-as-needed)

target_include_directories(wrapper
        PUBLIC /usr/local/include/dahua)

target_link_directories(wrapper
        PUBLIC /usr/local/lib/dahua)

target_link_libraries(wrapper dhnetsdk)
```

Then I use it to build another target called "library" (also shared object)

```
add_library(lib SHARED
        library.c buffer.c)

target_link_options(lib PUBLIC -Wl,--no-as-needed)

target_include_directories(lib
        PUBLIC /usr/local/include/dahua)

target_link_directories(lib
        PUBLIC /usr/local/lib/dahua
        PUBLIC ../cmake-build-debug-gcc/wrapper)

target_link_libraries(lib wrapper)
```

Finally I want to build a test executable and link it with those targets built before.

```
# Test executable
add_executable(test_x main.c)

target_link_options(test_x PUBLIC -Wl,--no-as-needed)

target_include_directories(test_x
        PUBLIC /usr/local/include/dahua)

target_link_directories(test_x
        PUBLIC /usr/local/lib/dahua
        PUBLIC ../cmake-build-debug-gcc/wrapper
        PUBLIC ../cmake-build-debug-gcc/library)

target_link_libraries(test_x lib)
```

When I try to build it I get a bunch of undefined references for functions that "wrapper" implement and functions that are implemented in 3rd party lib "dhnetsdk".

```
ld: ../wrapper/libwrapper.so: undefined reference to `CLIENT_SetDeviceMode(long, __EM_USEDEV_MODE, void*)'
ld: ../library/liblib.so: undefined reference to `DH_SDK_Init'
ld: ../library/liblib.so: undefined reference to `DH_DownloadByTime'
ld: ../library/liblib.so: undefined reference to `DH_SDK_Cleanup'
ld: ../library/liblib.so: undefined reference to `DH_Logout'
ld: ../library/liblib.so: undefined reference to `DH_SetDeviceMode'
ld: ../library/liblib.so: undefined reference to `DH_Login'
ld: ../wrapper/libwrapper.so: undefined reference to `CLIENT_StopDownload(long)'
...
```

At first, using `ldd` I've noticed that my "wrapper" and "lib" aren't even linked against this 3rd party library "dhnetsdk". So I added `-Wl,--no-as-needed`. After that `ldd` showed the dependency. But undefined references in the executable are still present.

When I `readelf -s libwrapper.so` it shows that all symbols in "dhnetsdk" lib are undefined. But as far as I understand this is expected as it will be resolved later, when it's actually used. The same is true for symbols defined in "wrapper", when I `readelf -s liblib.so`.

For me it looks like CMake knows about all the libs, knows where to find them, but for some mysterious reason denies to link it and resolve symbols when I try to build an executable. What am I missing here?

Comment: "For me it looks like CMake knows about all the libs, knows where to find them, but for some mysterious reason denies to link it" - CMake just calls the linker in a way you specify in your `CMakeLists.txt`. It is linker who output "undefine reference" errors. As `ldd` informs about dependency between wrapper and `dhnetsdk` library, it seems that given symbols (e.g. `CLIENT_SetDeviceMode`) is never defined in that library. Or the function is defined but with different parameters.

Comment: BTW, a function defined in **C++** library (`dh-wrap.cpp` in `wrapper`) cannot be used in **C** code (`library.c`, `main.c`). Probably, this the reason of the errors you got. You need to rename appropriate C files from `.c` to `.cpp` for compile them as C++.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you for answers. With your help I've figured it out - reason symbols were undefined, because I've mistyped `#ifdef _cplusplus` instead of `#ifdef __cplusplus`. So the function names were mangled both for `DH_` and original 3rd party `CLIENT_`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev should I close or delete the question as it's clearly not related to CMake?

Comment: If the problem in question is caused by a typo, and you don't think such typo to be interesting for others, then you may delete the question post. Many deleted questions could be resulted in restricted ability to post new questions on Stack Overflow. But single deleted post is definitely not a problem.